# How to create a system user/group that will appear in /etc/passwd and /etc/groups?

Tags: terminal, command-line, user-account

I want to programmatically create a system user (and group) for a new system service I'm working on.  I've followed the hints to use `dscl` here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/20702/how-do-i-create-user-accounts-from-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x-10-5

`dscl` supposedly creates the user but `id` and `groups` commands report that the user does not exist.  `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` also don't show the newly created user.

I'm basically looking for the functional equivalent of:

```
useradd -r -s /bin/false USERNAME
```

And I expect `id` and `groups` commands to work afterward.

Also, I see most system users listed in `/etc/passwd` have an underscore prefixed to their name (e.g. `_dovecot`).  Not sure why that is the case or if it is important but it'll be annoying if I have to use different user account names across platforms.

Comment: /etc/passwd is not used by macOS after it has booted - all the apis will use the data you see in dscl. What is trhe actual problem you have as not beind in /etc/passwd should not matter. dscl --read /Users/USERNAME UniqueID will give the id

Comment: The problem is that `id USERNAME` does not report that the user exists.

Comment: Does the dscl command read return data

Comment: Yes.  `dscl . -read /Users/username` returns data.

Comment: Did you create all of the required properties for a user with appropriate values (especially `UniqueID` and `PrimaryGroupID`, which must bothe be numbers)? Check carefully for typos or anything like that. Also, try rebooting to make sure all of the caches have been flushed.

Comment: Setting `PrimaryGroupID` appears to work.  Cross-integrating with `dsceditgroup` and some POSIX user/group functions was required.  Very fragile code though.  All other *NIX OSes have a single one-liner for creating system users.

Comment: @CubicleSoft So do recent versions of macOS -- `sysadminctl -addUser`. See [https://krypted.com/mac-os-x/using-sysadminctl-macos/](https://krypted.com/mac-os-x/using-sysadminctl-macos/).